# Should I still care about IE6?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [IE6: To support or not to support.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support)
>   [Do you plan to support IE 6 on your future projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304305/do-you-plan-to-support-ie-6-on-your-future-projects)

I've finished the design and about to code HTML for a website that will use fancy form elements and effects.

I'm wondering if I should support IE6? What are the latest stats? Do you support IE6 still?

Comment: The longer we will care for it , the longer the old crap will stay alive for :-/

Comment: Greg, that is somewhat true, however that question was active two years ago, and two years is a long time on the web. In 2008, supporting IE, specifically also IE6, was arguably very important. Today, not so much depending on your audience.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: This question is asked regularly; the one I linked to was just the first one that showed up in a search for "support ie6". Here's more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861669/shouldnt-we-ignore-ie6-and-ie7-users-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704361/should-we-bother-about-ie-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304305/do-you-plan-to-support-ie-6-on-your-future-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [W3Counter](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php), IE6 is used by more people than Opera, Safari, and any version of Chrome. It trails IE8 (#1), Firefox 3.6, and IE7. I would still care for a bit longer (especially if you are dealing with the general population).

However, [Google is apparently ready to phase out support](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8488751.stm), so perhaps the world's IE6 problems will go away sooner rather than later, as consumers follow Google's prompt to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

A good website should degrade gracefully. Make it work in IE6, but don't try to make the layout perfect.

Consider not just IE6, but somebody using Opera Mini, or another less capable mobile browser, or Lynx/Links, or a blind user with a screenreader. All of those combined add up to a decent fraction of your audience and if you don't have time to test all of those.

So, your site should still be usable, it just might not look quite as pretty, or it might require reloading a page instead of using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your audience context. If you are some traditional business or a big site with a high IE user proportion, by all means, use the hacks to get IE working, or risk losing customers.

However, if the IE population isn't as important to you, or there is just a general lack of IE users on your website (think web development blogs where most of the visitors are smart and don't use IE) then you can ignore IE.

I ignore Internet Explorer on my website as it's a web dev blog and the IE proportion is minuscule in the session logs.

Comment: Isn't that kind of a self-fulfilling prophecy? If you do not cater to a part of the population, they will soon leave and ignore you in turn?

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, it was something like 8% (Sorry, not 2% as I originally stated!) or so. Personally I think you should support at least IE6. It's not too difficult and will make you a more disciplined developer. At least that's how I see it. :)

EDIT:
And I still stand by my answer. IE6 is a pain, but not impossible. And for 8%, worth it.

Comment: Yes, I'm supporting IE, but not IE6.

Comment: This is wrong on many levels. IE6 usage is way above 2%, and it's a nightmare to try to write an even moderately complex website that works well in IE6.

Comment: Close, but it's about eight percent. See my answer - it really is about your audience and if IE is important. Stats source: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: It's not easy, but it's not that difficult either... and sorry, I guess that was the stat for IE5. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

[18% use it](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2) (Mostly corporates users who cant upgrade for some reason) so unless you want to cut out 1 in 5 customers you have to endure the pain.

Answer (score 0):

I only care for for IE 6 if client still wants , otherwise no and for IE 6 to make compatible I use this JavaScript.

http://divitodesign.com/css/let-ie6-behave-like-ie7/

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then these selectors will also work in IE6

#### CSS Selectors

- parent > child
- .multiple.classes
- :hover
- :first-child
- [attr]
- [attr="value"], [attr~="value"], [attr|="value"], [attr^="value"], [attr$="value"]
- [attr*="value"]

#### CSS

- Background-image – PNG alpha transparency (IE5.5+)
- Background-attachment – Support fixed positioning
- Position – Support fixed positioning
- Margin – Support auto (IE5.x)
- Cursor – Support pointer for IE5.x
- Display – Convert list-item to block for IE5.x

#### HTML

- img – PNG alpha transparency
- abbr – Bug fixed